# How do I make a custom block that has an image background with hotspots?

Tags: blocks, media

I am working on making a custom module with a block that contains a floor plan.  It will be an office, when you hover over employees desks it will have a bubble appear showing that employees project status and other information.  All instructions I can find for setting the image in the block uses css.  Is this how I need to do it? Will i be able to set regions for mouse over this way?

Comment: Hello. Please see help center, how to ask section. Especially part that says you should show your code if you want any help with your code. And if you don't want code, just tutorials, remember that requests for tutorials are off-topic here, too.

Comment: How to Ask
Is your question about the Drupal CMS?
We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.
Remember to report the Drupal version and relevant modules you are using. If your question is about code, include the relevant parts.
Nowhere does it say that a question needs to be about code or contain a code example.  I am asking for the best method for showing an image as the background a block, solutions could be suggested modules, to use css, to use menus in drupal to add the image, I'm not asking to be handed code.

Comment: If you notice, nowhere in the keywords or question do I mention php or mysql, I'm asking for the best method to display a block in the fashion that I need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the module [jQuery Map Hilight](https://drupal.org/project/jq_maphilight) which uses [jQuery maphilight plugin](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/) (visit the link to view demos).

Download from [David Lynch blog](http://davidlynch.org/blog/2008/03/maphilight-image-map-mouseover-highlighting/) / [GitHub](https://github.com/kemayo/maphilight).

Comment: Download from [David Lynch blog](http://davidlynch.org/blog/2008/03/maphilight-image-map-mouseover-highlighting/) / [GitHub](https://github.com/kemayo/maphilight).

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7 you can use

- [**qtip**](https://drupal.org/project/qtip/) module.
- If you don't want to use the module you can use [jQuery qtip plugins](http://jsfiddle.net/craga89/L6yq3/).
- Its better to make an Ajax request to get the user details, if you are trying to load more user details.